# How to add custom data to an EF Core model during OnModelCreating?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to write a method that performs some additional inspection during the model-building phase, then stores a custom object `CustomInfoModel` in the model that can be pulled back out later on when needed.

`CustomInfoModel` contains data which is specific to the model itself, so I don't want to have to build it each time a DbContext is created.

So my idea was to create an extension method on `ModelBuilder` and call it from `OnModelBuilding`. It seemed like an annotation was the best way to store this object, so I created the object, stored it as an annotation, then called `Ignore` so that it wouldn't be used:

```cs
public void AddCustomInfoModel(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var customModel = CustomInfoModel.FromBuilder(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.HasAnnotation(nameof(CustomInfoModel), customModel);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<CustomInfoModel>();
}
```

This seemed to work fine; I could later retrieve this object using `Model.FindAnnotation()` when needed. However, when trying to add a migration using `dotnet ef migrations add`, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'MyApp.CustomInfoModel'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.UnknownLiteral(Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Fragment(MethodCallCodeFragment fragment, Boolean typeQualified, String instanceIdentifier, Int32 indent)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Fragment(MethodCallCodeFragment fragment, String instanceIdentifier, Boolean typeQualified)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.GenerateAnnotations(String builderName, IAnnotatable annotatable, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder, Dictionary`2 annotations, Boolean inChainedCall, Boolean leadingNewline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpSnapshotGenerator.Generate(String modelBuilderName, IModel model, IndentedStringBuilder stringBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMetadata(String migrationNamespace, Type contextType, String migrationName, String migrationId, IModel targetModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Cannot scaffold C# literals of type 'MyApp.CustomInfoModel'. The provider should implement CoreTypeMapping.GenerateCodeLiteral to support using it at design time.
```

So my question is: is there a way to hide this annotation so that the database provider completely ignores it? Or is there a better way to store "extra" data in the model that is only created once but then is available to all future `DbContext` instances?

Answer (score 1):

From a code-first perspective, the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations) illustrates similar customization examples by implementing a replacement service for `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` that extends whichever provider-specific implementation you plan to use for your deployment(s). That is, you get an override method for fine-tuning a given provider's handling of whatever your custom data/operation is.

Perhaps you could examine the EF Core source code for a scaffolding counterpart that allows you to customize the scaffolded migration procedures? Or open an Issue on their GitHub to ask about such an API / request that they expand the API to include it if it doesn't exist (they appear to be quite responsive)?

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.